# Pointer trouble

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I am having trouble getting my pointers to work correctly.  In my main file I declare

```
Analysis2 analysis = Analysis2();
MaxResults maxresults = MaxResults( analysis);
```

Now in my MaxResults class, I want to point to analysis so that if any of its variables change I still get the right value.  Right now I declare the constructor in the MaxResults header as

```
MaxResults(Analysis2 analysis);
Analysis2 * analysis2;
```

And in the MaxResults class

```
MaxResults(Analysis2 analysis)
{
    analysis2 = analysis;
}
```

When I try to access things from analysis that changed, analysis2 doesn't seem to be keeping up.  How do I fix this, and is there an easy way to remember pointers and referencing and dereferencing in the future?

Comment: Which of those are supposed to be pointers? Please try to post something that vaguely resembles C++.

Comment: I want analysis 2 to point to analysis (and therefore point to all the changes made after that assignment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want `MaxResults` to keep a pointer to an `Analysis2` object, you should do it like this:

```
class MaxResults {

 public:
     MaxResults(Analysis* an) : analysis(an) {}

 private:
     Analysis* analysis;
};
```

and construct it like this:

```
Analysis2 analysis = Analysis2();
MaxResults maxresults = MaxResults( &analysis);
```

Note the use of the address-of operator (&) to capture the address of `analysis` and pass it as pointer to the `MaxResults` constructor, which saves the pointer in a member (using an initialization list, which is more or less equivalent to doing `analysis = an` in the constructor's body, just in case the `:` syntax is new to you).

For further reading, have a look at references (once your got a better understanding of pointers, of course). In this case, references would probably be preferred.

Comment: I would *not* recommend using call by reference and holding onto the object longer than the functional call itself. Using pointers is perfectly fine here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure how that's compiling; it shouldn't. The problem is your constructor.

First, if your constructor simply takes an `Analysis2` parameter, that parameter is pass-by-value; the object is always copied. There's no way that the pointer can point to the actual object that was passed in, since your constructor only gets a copy of it. You need to use a reference parameter:

```
MaxResults(Analysis2& analysis);
```

Second, you can't directly assign an object to a pointer to that object. You need to use the `&` operator to take the address of the object.

```
MaxResults(Analysis2& analysis)
{
    analysis2 = &analysis;
}
```

On an unrelated note: it's good style to use a member initializer list for the constructor.

```
MaxResults(Analysis2& analysis)
    : analysis2(&analysis)
{
}
```

Comment: It was compiling until I realized that analysis2 wasn't mirroring analysis, then when I changed the code to what you see above, it broke, and I just didn't know how to assign my pointers properly

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah, it broke because the type of `analysis2` is pointer-to-Analysis2, and the type of `analysis` is just Analysis2. The compiler won't convert from one to the other automatically; you need to use operators. The operator that goes from an object to a pointer to that object is `&`; the other direction is `*`. (Note: those technically aren't conversions, but that's the general idea.)

Comment: I wouldn't mix references and pointers like that. Just use pointers and have the client type the extra `&` character.

Comment: I personally code to a style where a pointer in a parameter means that memory is somehow being manipulated (i.e. the receiver might need to dealloc the passed-in object, or it might be an array or other pointer arithmetic). So I would rather see a reference here, especially because (I assume) there is no reason for the data member to be null. And since you can't copy a class with a reference data member, my personal opinion is that a reference parameter with a pointer data member is the most reasonable way to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `MaxResults maxresults = MaxResults(analysis);`, your constructor gets a copy of `analysis`. You need to pass in the reference to `analysis` so the the constructor gets the address that it can store in a pointer. That way `maxresults` has a pointer to the original object, rather than just a copy of the original object.

Do something like this in the header:

```
MaxResults(Analysis2 *analysis);
Analysis2* analysis2;
```

Do this in the class definition:

```
MaxResults(Analysis2 *analysis)
{
    analysis2 = analysis;
}
```

And create the objects this way:

```
Analysis2 analysis = Analysis2();
MaxResults maxresults = MaxResults(&analysis);
```